# Is there a way to access the "time since last full charge" value in iOS using objective-c?

Tags: ios, time, battery

In **settings**, under **usage**, there are values for **time elapsed since last full charge**. Is there a way to access these values in iOS?

I have searched but I have been unable to locate anything myself. Have i **overlooked** a particular part of the **documentation** or is it completely **impossible** to do at this time?

Comment: did you find the solution now?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible with Public API's. The method may be in a Private API, but Ive never seen it mentioned on any forum or blog. The most you can get from the Public API is battery level, time to charge, whats the charging status (plugged in, not plugged in).